# change value of textview in a recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, api, android-recyclerview

guys I'm using multiple api request with the same   response and displaying it into a recycling
view
but in those response I get a user_id instead of user name but I need to display the user name into the recyclerview
this image breaks down what i need to do : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdQ6e.png

so this is my adapter class where I tried to make a hashmap using another api request and  making a hashmap with <user_id,user_name> and trying to use it in the holder class to display the user name but it didn't work  :

```
public class FollowupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {

Map<String, String> userMap1 = new HashMap<>();

private Context Context1 ;
private List<TraitementTicketModel> followuplist;




public FollowupAdapter(Context mContext, List<TraitementTicketModel> followuplist) {
    this.Context1 = mContext;
    this.followuplist = followuplist;


}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(followuplist.get(position).getTaskcategories_id()!=null) {
        return 3;
    }else if (followuplist.get(position).getSolutiontypes_id()!=null){
        return 2;

    }
    return 1;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(Context1);
    if (viewType==1){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.followupitem, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolderFollowup(view);
    }else if (viewType==2){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.solutionitem, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolderSolution(view);
    }
    else
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.taskitem, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolderTask(view);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    displayusers();

    if(followuplist.get(position).getTaskcategories_id()!=null) {
        ViewHolderTask viewHolderTask = (ViewHolderTask) holder;
        viewHolderTask.users_id.setText(userMap1.get(followuplist.get(position).getUsers_id()));
        viewHolderTask.date.setText(followuplist.get(position).getDate());
        viewHolderTask.content.setText(html2text(followuplist.get(position).getContent()));

    }else if(followuplist.get(position).getSolutiontypes_id()!=null){
        ViewHolderSolution viewHolderSolution = (ViewHolderSolution) holder;
        viewHolderSolution.users_id.setText(userMap1.get(followuplist.get(position).getUsers_id()));
        viewHolderSolution.date.setText(followuplist.get(position).getDate());
        viewHolderSolution.content.setText(html2text(followuplist.get(position).getContent()));



    }
    else {
        ViewHolderFollowup viewHolderFollowup = (ViewHolderFollowup) holder;
        viewHolderFollowup.users_id.setText(userMap1.get(followuplist.get(position).getUsers_id()));
        viewHolderFollowup.content.setText(html2text(followuplist.get(position).getContent()));
        viewHolderFollowup.titre.setText(followuplist.get(position).getTitre());
        viewHolderFollowup.date.setText(followuplist.get(position).getDate());
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return followuplist.size(); }


 public static class ViewHolderFollowup extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView users_id;
    TextView date;
    TextView content;
    TextView titre;


    public ViewHolderFollowup(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        users_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_id_followup);
        date =itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_followup);
        content=itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenu_followup);
        titre=itemView.findViewById(R.id.titre_followup);
    }

}
  public static class ViewHolderTask extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView users_id;
    TextView date;
    TextView content;



    public ViewHolderTask(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        users_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_id_task);
        date =itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_task);
        content=itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenu_task);

    }
}

public static class ViewHolderSolution extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView users_id;
    TextView date;
    TextView content;



    public ViewHolderSolution(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        users_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_id_solution);
        date =itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_solution);
        content=itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenu_solution);

    }

}

    public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.parse(html).text()).text();
}
public List addToList(List<TraitementTicketModel> list) {


    if(this.followuplist.addAll(list)){
        Sort(followuplist);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();


    return this.followuplist;
}
private List Sort (List<TraitementTicketModel> datalist){

    Collections.sort(datalist, new Comparator<TraitementTicketModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TraitementTicketModel o1, TraitementTicketModel o2) {
            return o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate());
        }
    });

    return datalist;
}
private void displayusers() {
    SharedPreferences sp =Context1.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("tokenPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sestoken = sp.getString("token","");

    Retrofit retrofit= RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
    final Api api= retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<List<User>> call = api.getUser(sestoken);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

            if (response.code() != 200){
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: something is wrong"+response.code() );



            }
            List<User> users = response.body();





            for (User user : users) {
                if (userMap.get(user.getId()) == null)
                    userMap.put(user.getId(), user.getName());
            }






        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {


        }
    });

}

private Map<String, String> PutMap(HashMap<String, String> userMap) {


    userMap1=userMap;

    return userMap1;
}
```

}

this hashmap I tried didn't work appreciate any solution or idea I'm really stuck in this

Comment: You didn't really say what the exact problem was, except "it didn't work". Why don't you make the network request to fetch one list, then make the network request to fetch the usernames, then construct a list with an object UserWithId where you put both together and then supply that to your recyclerview adapter, which has no business doing any of the work you're asking it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter's job is to adapt a data model into a series of view holders, not to transform, combine, fetch, mutate, etc. a different series of data coming from different sources.

Ask yourself this question: if you could "magically" call an object like this `repository.getList()` that would return a `List` of `Something` and that `Something` had three fields:

```
class Something {
   String id;
   String userName;
   String content;
   String type; //maybe useful for the Adapter to pick what type...
   ... anything else you need
}
```

So you have a `List<Something>()` that you can pass to your adapter, wouldn't your adapter suddenly be super simple?

That's what you need to do; remove all the logic that does *not* belong in the adapter (I expect only to have a `onCreateViewHolder` `onBindViewHolder` `getItemViewType` and that's it).

You're making a big problem into your adapter, which already has a lot of other responsibilities to carry. This data problem (putting the user + id + content) in a single object is a problem of your data source/repository, and *not the adapter of a recycler view*.

**Transform your data before you pass it to your adapter**. Your life, your fellow developers, and the future you, will be grateful.